# GCC inclusion of AVX512's "Fused Multiply Add" instructions when compiling for Cascade-Lake processors

Tags: gcc, intel, cpu-architecture, avx512, fma

According to [gcc's documention](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html), compiling with "-march=cascadelake" does not enable the flag -AVX512IFMA (which, if I understand correctly, enables support for AVX512's FMA instructions). In contrast, this flag is included for example when compiling with "-march=cannonlake" and "-march=tigerlake".

Howeover, accorindg to Intel, Cascade-Lake's processors actually include 2 AVX-512 FMA units each (here's an [example](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/198017/intel-core-i9-10980xe-extreme-edition-processor-24-75m-cache-3-00-ghz.html), and as far as I can tell, this true for any Cascade-Lake processor).

Can anyone please clarify this behaviour? Am I misinterpreting the meaning of the AVX512IFMA flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AVX-512 FMA units on SKX/CSX support the FMA instructions that are part of the `AVX512F` extensions. These instructions operate on floating-point operands. The `AVX512IFMA` instructions operate on 52-bit unsigned integer operands. They are different sets of instructions. Wikipedia has [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512) of instructions in each of the AVX-512 extensions.